Matching pair of socks question

Ramon has four pairs of black socks and two pairs of white socks, and
wants to buy more. He decides he needs 12 more pairs for 36 socks in
all.Ramon wants to maximize the probability that when he picks two
random socks from the 36 in his drawer, he gets a matching pair. If
the store sells socks in packs of four pairs (i.e. eight socks), what
should Ramon buy?

I know the answer to this question is 3 black pairs, and I intuitively understand why this is the case. However, when I tried to solve it algebraically, I made the following logical steps:

When choosing the first two socks, P(socks match) + P(socks don't match) = 1
If we want to maximizing P(socks match), we can equivalently minimizing P(socks don't match), which will be a bit easier.
If we let $b$ be the number of packs of black socks we buy, the total number of black socks will be $8+8b$ and white socks $28-8b$. Then, P(socks don't match) = $\frac{(8+8b)(28-8b)}{36 \choose 2}$
We can minimize this by taking the derivative and solving for the critical point, which definitely doesn't give 0 and instead gives 1.25.

I'm not sure which of these steps is the source of my logical error. Would appreciate any help pointing it out!!

It looks like you mixed packages and pairs

Seems like a good excuse to learn about the $L^1$ and $L^2$ norms.

Your error comes from assuming the zero of the derivative is a minimum, whereas it is a maximum.  If he could buy $1.25$ packs of black socks he would have $18$ of each color and there would be $324$ ways to select a mismatched pair.  The minimum occurs at one of the ends of the interval.  You need to check $b=0, b=3$ and will discover at $b=0$ there are only $128$ ways to select mismatched socks.  If he didn't already own any socks the maximum chance of matching socks would be to buy all the same kind.  The second derivative test will tell you that $1.25$ is a local maximum.

I think your step 3 is wrong. Let $n$ be the total number of socks, $b$ the total number of black socks, and $w=n-b$ be the total number of white socks. The probability of a mismatch is the probability that you pick a black sock and then a white sock, plus the probability that you pick a white sock and then a black sock. The first event has probability
$$\frac{b}{b+w}\frac{w}{b+w-1} = \frac{b(n-b)}{n(n-1)}.$$
The second event has the same probability:
$$\frac{w}{b+w}\frac{b}{b+w-1} = \frac{b(n-b)}{n(n-1)}.$$
Per your original post, we now want to minimize this mismatch probability by varying $b$ while holding $n$ fixed. The first-order conditions imply $b=1/2$. However, the second-order conditions reveal that this is a maximum, not a minimum: having equal numbers of black and white socks maximizes the chance of a mismatch. Thus, the minima occur at the boundaries of the domain: $b=0,b=n$. Either of these would serve to set the probability of mismatch to zero: if you have all black socks or all white socks you won't end up with any mismatched socks.
However, per the stated problem, we must have $b=8,10,12,14,16,18, \textrm{ or } 20$. We then pretend that $b$ is a continuous variable between 8 and 20. The minimum would occur, then, at $b=8$ or $b=20$. Returning to our original expression, we find that choosing 8 black socks minimizes the probability to $16/45$, whereas choosing 20 black socks would give a mismatch probability of $32/63$. Note that it's not impossible for the mismatch probability to go above 1/2, since drawing a sock of one color on the first draw increases the odds of drawing a sock of the other color on the second draw.
